# Why did Pandavas killed Nishada woman and her sons while escaping the house of lac?

Tags: mahabharata

In Jatugriha Parva we see that Pandavas ended up killing Nishada woman and her five sons.

> *Desirous of obtaining food, there came, as though impelled by fate, to that feast, **in course of her wanderings, a Nishada woman, the mother of five children, accompanied by all her sons. O king, she, and her children, intoxicated with the wine they drank, became incapable. Deprived of consciousness and more dead than alive, she with all her sons lay down in that mansion to sleep.** Then when all the inmates of the house lay down to sleep, there began to blow a violent wind in the night**. Bhima then set fire to the house just where Purochana was sleeping. Then the son of Pandu set fire to the door of that house of lac.[1]***

Those innocent were just used as cover by Pandavas to make a public impression that Pandavas and Kunti had died. I mean, why did they kill innocents just to save themselves?

Comment: What would you do if you are in this situation?